# Foreign key column inserted as null in java

Tags: java, hibernate

[code of entities 'employee' and 'timelog'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6T6m.png)Problem :
I have two tables employee and timelog.Timelog has foreign key relationship with employee table(employee id).But every insert to timelog table inserts employee id as null.Below is the code snippet of the model 'employee' and 'timelog' and the logic.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "employee/{id}/timelog/tabdata",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void timeLogging(@RequestBody ArrayList<TimeLogDto> tabData, @PathVariable("id") Integer id){
        Employee e = employeeRepository.findOne(id);        
        tabData.forEach(log->{
            e.addLog(timeLogRepository.save(log.createTimeLog()));
        });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Code for entities is missing.

Comment: Your edit messed up.  Review the Question and do the edit again.  And while you are at it, fix up the line breaks in your code to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Its very annoying, I cant add more code here.Error: more lines of code than explanantion

Comment: I have added an image please check